# For loop return an index number matching

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with a for loop. I want to return the index that matches with `num` against fruits. When `num=2`, I want it to return "apple". What am I doing wrong?

```
    var num=2;
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    for (var i=0;i <fruits.length;i++) {
      if (fruits[i] === num) {
        console.log("matched, it is" + fruits[num])
      } else {
        console.log("did not match")
      }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need a loop? Why not `fruits[num]`?

Comment: Just to add a little clarity, fruits[i] returns the name of the fruit at index i. So fruits[i] will never === num, unless a number is added to the array.

Answer (score 2):

The condition that you should be checking against is

`if(i === num)` instead of `if(fruits[i] === num)`.

You want to compare index `i` against number `num` and not the value at index `i` in `fruits` array against `num`.

For example: `fruits[0]` is "Banana", `fruits[1]` is "Orange",...so on. What you are doing is comparing "Banana", "Orange",...etc against `num` value 2 when you should be comparing value of `i` which goes from 0,1,..3 against `num` value 2.

Also, like @Kamyar pointed out, you can directly access `fruits[num]`, probably after a sanity check in case `fruits` gets populated from an outside source:

```js
var num=2;
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
if(fruits != null && num >= 0 && num < fruits.length) {
    console.log("matched, it is " + fruits[num])
}
else{
    console.log("did not match")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare `num` with array index `i`:

```
if (i == num) {
   console.log("matched, it is" + fruits[num])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (fruits[i] === num) {...}` - `fruits[i]` is an element inside the `fruits` array at `i` position, not an index. Compare it with the index `i === num` instead.

```js
var num = 2,
    fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
  if (i === num) {
    console.log("matched, it is " + fruits[num])
  } else {
    console.log("did not match")
  }
}
```